# How I can search the documents that have been filtered using the Metadata Navigation term inside my document library

Tags: list, document-library, search, filter, metadata-navigation

I have document library inside my team site inside SP 2013, now I have enabled the metadata navigation site feature. which allow me to filter my documents using metadata navigation. But I am facing the following problem:-

1. I have a drop-down list named “Document type” which is added to the document library, now if I click on “Policy + Procedures” choice then all the documents that have the “Policy + Procedures” will be filtered as follow:-

[image]

2. But now I want to only search these filtered documents . for example if I type the word “working” then nothing will be returned:-

[image]
Although the filtered documents contain the word “working”. And f I search the whole site , then these documents will be shown in the search. So my question is how I can search the documents that have been filtered using the metadata navigation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you might want to add the corresponding metadata tags to your documents.

example

Library A
 folder 1
   Folder 1.1

if you are searching for documents that are in folder 1.1 you have to tag them with the correct metadata tag.

Or you might want to make a new refiner and add it to your search page.